# Calculation of bessel function versus matlab solution

Tags: functions, special-functions, matlab, transcendental-equations

I am looking to calculate the Bessel function of the first kind $J_o(\beta)$.  I am using the formula (referenced from wikipedia) to accomplish this.
$$J_\alpha (\beta) = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^m}{m!\Gamma(m+\alpha +1)} \left(\frac{\beta}{2}\right)^{2m+\alpha}$$

I am also aware of that MATLAB has a function which can calculate the solution as well.  The function call is $besselj(nu,Z)$.  However, what I am finding is that there is a discrepancy between what my $for$ loop calculates and what MATLAB outputs.

Does anyone see why this might be happening?  I have included my code for reference:

```
loop_var = 100;
beta = 0.120;
alpha = 0;

sum = 0;
amp = 0;

[matl,ierr]  =besselj(alpha,beta)

for m=0:loop_var
    amp=amp+((-1)^m)/(factorial(m)*gamma(m+alpha+1))*(beta/2)^(2*m+alpha);
end
amp
```

Thanks for all comments and suggestions.

EDIT: Thanks to Fabian and Ed for catching that error.

I suppose as a "followup" question, the wikipedia formula and that MATLAB function seem to only match for "small" values of $\beta$.  After $\beta$ is great than approximately 10, there is some error between the two values.  Does anyone then know how the Matlab number is obtained?

Comment: Shouldn't it be for `m=0:loop_var` (I'm not good Matlab programmer, its just a hunch).

Comment: @Fabian Good catch.  I've fixed that.

Comment: @suzu I've addressed your edited question in my answer.

Comment: @EdGorcenski Thanks to you as well!  I've now edited my question a bit with a follow-up that I hope has a quick fix as well :)

Comment: Since you have a $\beta^m$ term in there (actually $\beta^{2m+\alpha}$, but we can ignore the factor of 2 and the $\alpha$), then what happens as $m$ becomes large is that $\beta^m$ blows up for $\beta > 1$. There is no simple fix for this. The easiest solution might be to solve the Bessel's differential equation with those parameters, using an appropriate ODE method.

Comment: @EdGorcenski In lieu of starting a new question, perhaps you can provide some comments to this (related) question.  Since it appears simpler to use the besselj call in MATLAB, is there a nice way to force one of the input parameters to be a transfer function?  I.E. for $besselj(nu, Z)$ Z is an integrator function $(1/s)$?  Matlab only seems to want numeric input parameters, but I would like to know if there is a clever way around this.

Thanks.

Comment: @suzu I think it would be best to make that another question. I'm not even sure what it would mean to call `besselj(nu,1/s)`. The function `besselj(nu,Z)` computes one of the solutions to Bessel's differential equation; I'm not sure it makes any sense at all to replace an independent variable with a transfer function in the analytic evaluation of an ODE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for m=loop_var
    amp=amp+((-1)^m)/(factorial(m)*gamma(m+alpha+1))*(beta/2)^(2*m+alpha);
end
```

This code only executes the loop once.

```
for m=0:loop_var
    amp=amp+((-1)^m)/(factorial(m)*gamma(m+alpha+1))*(beta/2)^(2*m+alpha);
end
```

This code is correct (notice the **`0:`** after `m=`).

For your edited question...

From the MATLAB `besselj` documentation:

> Algorithms
>
> The besselj function uses a Fortran MEX-file to call a library
>   developed by D.E. Amos [3] [4].
>
> [3] Amos, D.E., "A Subroutine Package for Bessel Functions of a Complex Argument and Nonnegative Order," Sandia National Laboratory Report, SAND85-1018, May, 1985.
>
> [4] Amos, D.E., "A Portable Package for Bessel Functions of a Complex Argument and Nonnegative Order," Trans. Math. Software, 1986.

The first paper can be found [here](http://infoserve.sandia.gov/sand_doc/1985/851018.pdf).