# What is the algorithm used by Matlab for computing the Bessel function?

Tags: algorithms, computational-mathematics

I am quite curious about the algorithm behind. It is definitely not the power series expansion, right?

So, what is the trick? I cannot find it in the help file of Matlab.

Comment: Possibly related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191118/calculation-of-bessel-function-versus-matlab-solution

Comment: For large values, it is probably computed with its asymptotic expansion. The series requires a lot of terms for convergence for large values (and it is very poorly behaved - obviously) so they likely do not do this for large values.

Comment: It would be better to specify which [Bessel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) and what arguments interest you.  Not only are there Bessel function of the first and second kind, there is a (complex-valued) parameter defining each family.

Answer (score 1):

This is from the SE post I linked to in the comment; I don't know if this is the algorithm used in the most recent version of Matlab though:

http://prod.sandia.gov/techlib/access-control.cgi/1985/851018.pdf

Related post: [Calculation of bessel function versus matlab solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191118/calculation-of-bessel-function-versus-matlab-solution)